# Trying to identify threaded round 2-way power connector on a radio

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to find a power connector for a Maxon DM200 Mobitex radio terminal. As far as I'm aware, the part of he manufacturer who made this radio closed down some years ago, and there's no support available.

I've uploaded some photos of the connector to Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxFaU.jpg

There's a logo on the back of the connector which looks like a letter "W" in a circle.

Here are front and rear views of it.

[image: front view]

[image: rear view]

Here is the top view of the connector.

[image: top view]

Some facts and figures:

- Connector mating section thread -- I measured this at 12.7mm, it could be a loose-tolerance 13mm. There are only 3 complete threads.
- The back mounting nut isn't shaped (eg hex), it's completely round with two notches. I guess you'd use a pin spanner to install and remove it.
- The panel hole seems to be around 12mm diameter.
- There's a foam or rubber gasket (hard to tell which, it's perished) between the socket's bezel and the front panel. It clearly pushes in from the front.
- Pins are 1.5mm diameter and 2mm diameter. This is the only polarity keying I can see on the connector; there's no bump or notch polarising aid like the GX16 connector and most screw-in DIN plugs have.
- Pin spacing is about 4mm.

Does anyone know what this connector might be? I've ruled out GX12 and GX16, but either might work as a replacement.

Comment: +1 for the details and good pictures for an identification question. I'm sure I have some of those in a box of old audio stuff, but I have no idea what they are called.

Comment: With only 2 wires soldered, just replace it with something newer that will take the current & voltage.

Comment: @SolarMike - yeah that's what I was thinking. I've just had a GX12-2 plug and socket arrive, and that's a mechanical fit for the case but sadly the plug isn't compatible.
I'm starting to suspect this might be a custom connector.

Comment: Your 12.7 mm thread diameter may really be 0.50 inch.

Comment: Ask here for a match http://linhkienchatluong.vn/jack-gx16/jack-gx16-2p-duccai_sp796_ct4389.aspx

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it and the thread I'd say it's a 2-pin aviation connector (such as the one depicted here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-Sale-1-Set-GX16-2-Pin-Screw-Type-Electrical-Aviation-Plug-Socket-Connector/201465426325). However this one has one of the pins wider than the other (and the center notch is missing too), so this could be one of those lousy "proprietary" designs derived from the (more widely used) aviation connector design. You could give one of these aviation connectors a try and if it doesn't work out just unscrew the whole connector from behind and solder in something more standardized instead (perhaps even the said aviation connector).

Comment: That's what I thought too -- the nearest in size was the GX12-2 (which fits perfectly into the panel cutout). The aviation connector went half-way on then got stuck.

I've since removed the original factory connector and fitted the GX12-2 aviation connector, after the supplier quoted an extortionate price for a replacement cable.

Comment: @philpem I honestly think that that's the best thing you could've done. The original connector doesn't seem to be a standard connector at all and most of the obscure proprietary ones are self-serving anyway.

Comment: The only connector company I know with a W is Weidmueller yet they have nothing like this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exact, however switchcraft has a similar part. It is a 2 position and is threaded. MFG part number SL102M 
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/switchcraft-inc/SL102M/SL102M-ND/413399

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the only information I have found its a custom cable and connector made only for that radio and is £50 hope it helps maybe contact the person in the thread and see if he knows where to get one from,

https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/need-help-iding-a-12-7mm-2-pin-round-connector/

Answer (score -1):

looks very much like the two pin din used on microphones 
https://www.americanradiosupply.com/microphone-plugs/

Comment: The OP has already ruled that out. Polarization is done via pin diameter, rather than any sort of key on the body.

Comment: So I see   can it not be replaced with a new socket and connector. Maybe...